# A way to distribute string union to another Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, union-types

I currently have some Typescript code that looks like this :

```
type UserRole = "admin" | "partner" | "associate";

type User<Role extends UserRole> = {
    // ...
    role: Role;
   //  ...
}

type Users = User<"admin"> | User<"partner"> | User<"associate">
```

I use the `Role` type parameter on the `User` type to have dynamic typing over other properties of `User` in a `switch(user.role)` block.

Is there a way here to not manually write `type Users = User<"admin"> | User<"partner"> | User<"associate">`, but to "loop" over the UserRole string union instead, in order to distribute it to the User type ?

In other words, how could I write a type that would "distribute" the string union on my `User` type this way :

```
type Distribute<T, S> = // ?????
type Users = Distribute<User, UserRole>; // = User<"admin"> | User<"partner"> | User<"associate">
```

Thanks in advance,

Stay safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the distributive property of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Since we don't actually want to use the conditional part of conditional type, we will use an always true condition such as `T extends T`

```
type UserRole = "admin" | "partner" | "associate";

type User<Role extends UserRole> = {
    // ...
    role: Role;
   //  ...
}
type DistributeUsers<T  extends UserRole> = T extends T ? User<T> : never
type Users = DistributeUsers<UserRole>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgJQPYBtoF4oCICGAJgLYCWAdrlAD55j6LDlJW0FxyoDGp+wEuANwAoYaEiwEiADxpMUCAA9+5QnElI5EAHxQcAb2FRjUAPSmoAOmtGTiDBABcULSJPnj1y8IC+Y8NAAIqRwwIikAEYArvzwSHDSACrGSipqGigOujjJqRCq6skA-BlJus7MAG5I-hJxiOo4waHh0bFSCfVa2kA)